# Spotify API fetch giving errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

Here is my function:

```
const APIController = async () => {
    const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTID //process.env.VITE_CLIENTID
    const clientSecret = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTSECRET // process.VITE_CLIENTSECRET

    const result = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret)
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    })

    const data = await result.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

export default APIController
```

And here is the use of that function in my component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import APIController from "../api/APIController"

const LandingPage = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    APIController()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}

export default LandingPage
```

I consistently get these 2 errors:

- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

The imports are working just fine, at least to my knowledge. I also tried running the script with node APIController.js terminal command but that also did not work (and it actually doesn't recognize the environment variables when I try that).

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not supposed to make these API calls in the browser and leak your API secrets.

Comment: @gre_gor any suggestion on how to do that? I thought that environment variables in a git ignore were enough.

Comment: Do them in the backend.

Comment: @gre_gor. Can you post a resource that I can use to help me do that?

Answer (score -2):

The error message suggests that the fetch request to the Spotify API is being blocked by the Same Origin Policy. To resolve this issue, you can use a proxy server or the Spotify Web API SDK.
Here's an example of how you can use a proxy server to make the request:

```
const APIController = async () => {
    const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTID //process.env.VITE_CLIENTID
    const clientSecret = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTSECRET // process.VITE_CLIENTSECRET

    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const apiUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';

    const result = await fetch(proxyUrl + apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret)
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    })

    const data = await result.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

export default APIController
```

This code uses the cors-anywhere proxy server to make the request to the Spotify API. The proxyUrl variable is set to the URL of the proxy server, and the apiUrl variable is set to the URL of the Spotify API. The fetch function is then called with the combined URL, and the response is returned as JSON.
Alternatively, you can use the Spotify Web API SDK to make the request. Here's an example of how you can use the SDK:

```
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

const APIController = async () => {
    const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTID //process.env.VITE_CLIENTID
    const clientSecret = import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENTSECRET // process.VITE_CLIENTSECRET

    const result = await spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant({
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret
    });

    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

export default APIController;
```

This code uses the spotify-web-api-js library to make the request to the Spotify API. The clientCredentialsGrant function is called with the client_id and client_secret parameters, and the response is returned as an object.

Comment: Have you actually used `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`? It's not meant to be used in production.

Comment: And I don't see any `clientCredentialsGrant` method in the `spotify-web-api-js` library.

Comment: I  got TypeError: spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant is not a function